# VBA excel - find column and filter it

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I'm new to VBA and trying to learn by myself for some work purposes. I've been trying to create a macro that will find a column in my worksheet and then filter it by a specific word. Usually I find codes in google and just edit them but I have troubles with this one..

What I was able to find:

```
Sub sorting()

Dim col As String, cfind As Range

Worksheets(1).Activate

col = "Type"

Set cfind = Cells.Find(what:=col, lookat:=xlWhole)

ActiveSheet.Cells.Sort key1:=cfind, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Now I tried changing the "sort" part to autofilter. But it doesn't work at all..

```
.Range("A1:D1").AutoFilter Field:="col", Criteria1:="Virtual"
```

Could you please help?
thanks!
Coco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [Autofilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) method, the `Field` parameter is *"The integer offset of the field on which you want to base the filter (from the left of the list; the leftmost field is field one)."*

edited to enhance the code after some OP's clarifications:

Option Explicit

```
Sub autofiltering()
    Dim col As String, cfind As Range

    col = "Type"
    With Worksheets("AF") '<-- reference your relevant worksheet (change "AF" to your actual worksheet name)
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) '<-- reference its row 1 cells from column 1 rightwards to last not empty one
            Set cfind = .Find(what:=col, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<-- look for the wanted column header
            If Not cfind Is Nothing Then '<-- if the header has been found
                .AutoFilter Field:=cfind.Column, Criteria1:="Virtual" '<-- filter all columns of the referenced row cells

                ' do your things
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<-- show all rows back and remove autofilter buttons
    End With
```

Comment: you are welcome. furthermore assuming columns headers are in row 1  you may want to restrict the `Find()` call on the first row only `Set cfind = .Rows(1).Find(what:=col, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)`

Comment: see edited code, where I added comments to possibly help you through it. the key is to 1) use references (through the use of `WIth - End With` block) to objects (worksheets, ranges) and then have other operations refer to them by the use the dot (`.`) suffix 2) restrict the ranges to their minimum needed extension so as not to have performance issues (accessing cells is time consuming)

Comment: looks good! however I don't know how to do a simple selection on what was found: cfind.select doesn't seem to work.. is there something more I have to add to it?

Comment: `cfind.Select ` _has_ to work if placed after the `If Not cfind Is Nothing Then ` check. What _"doesn't seem to work"_?

Comment: working now, I put it in the wrong place! :) thanks so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Function columnfilter(sheetName As String)

lastcolumnnumber = Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

a = columnnumber_index(sheetName, "Your column name")
b = columnnumber_index(sheetName,"Your column name")
e = columnnumber_index(sheetName, "Your column name")
f = columnnumber_index(sheetName, "Your column name")

H = columnnumber_index(sheetName, "Your column name")
I = columnnumber_index(sheetName, "Your column name")
j = columnnumber_index(sheetName, "Your column name")
 

Debug.Print a
Debug.Print b
Debug.Print c
Debug.Print d
Debug.Print e
Debug.Print f
Debug.Print G
Debug.Print H
Debug.Print I


Worksheets(sheetName).AutoFilterMode = False

With Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A1")

.AutoFilter Field:=a, Criteria1:="value"
.AutoFilter Field:=b, Criteria1:="value"
.AutoFilter Field:=H, Criteria1:="<>value"
.AutoFilter Field:=f, Criteria1:="=value"
.AutoFilter Field:=I, Criteria1:="value"

  
End With



End Function

Function columnnumber_index(ByVal sheetName As String, columnname As String)

lastcolumnnumber = 0


lastcolumnnumber = Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


For c = 1 To lastcolumnnumber

If Worksheets(sheetName).Cells(1, c).Value = columnname Then

columnnumber_index = c


Exit For

End If

Next c

End Function
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).